# Thunderbolt 3 pci card that works with Ubuntu 20.10 Desktop - Suggestions wanted

Tags: 20.10, thunderbolt

I want to connect my Mac and my Ubuntu togheter to transfer files, but because of this I need a Thunderbolt 3 PCI extension card. I've been looking for some time on diffrent websites but I am unsure that Ubuntu 20.10 supports them? Can anyone suggest a card for me or confirm that Ubuntu has drivers?

ASUS ThunderboltEX 3-TR  
https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/Accessories/THUNDERBOLTEX-3-TR/HelpDesk_Download/

Lenovo ThinkStation Rear Riser card Thunderbolt 3 
https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories-and-monitors/cables-and-adapters/adapters/ACCKIT-BO-Rear-TBT-to-PCIe-Riser-Card/p/4XH0Y77510

Comment: This site frowns on making hardware suggestions.

Comment: @David the problem is that I need a card that Ubuntu supports. I cannot afford to purcase all cards to test if they works with Ubuntu or not.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about hardware recommendations. See [site help on this subject](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Europa
Any TB3 card should work on Intel machine.
I assume you have an Asus machine?

20.10 (Only Ubuntu I've used so far) supports TB3.
I'm running Ubuntu on Intel machine with Win10 latest.

I'm starting on Ubuntu myself from Win 10 and MacOS.
Ask away.  Hope this helps (a bit)